Django formtools' "done" method is not getting called on form submission
I am trying to build a multistep html form using Django formtools. I have 2 forms with 2 fields at most. After filling the last form (i.e. step 2) and clicking the submit button, I am taken back to step 1 instead of the "done" method being called. And the whole thing just becomes a never ending loop.

Here is my code.

forms.py
class ListingForm1(forms.Form):
    company_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
    }))
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=500, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
    }))


class ListingForm2(forms.Form):
    business_category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=BusinessCategory.objects.all(), required=True,
                                         widget=forms.Select(attrs={
                                             'id': 'cat-select',
                                             'class': 'form-control',
                                         }))

views.py
class AddListing(SessionWizardView):
    form_list = [ListingForm1, ListingForm2]
    template_name = 'registration/listing_templates/addlisting.html' 
    
    def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("form submitted")
    

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block css %}
<!-- <link href="{% static 'dashboard_assets/css/custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"> -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
    #div_id_2-allkws{
        display: none !important;
    }

    .select2{
        width: 100% !important;

    }
    .select2-container .select2-selection--single{
        height: calc(2.68rem + 2px) !important;
    }
    .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{
        top: 10px !important;
    }
</style>
{% endblock css %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content-container container">
    

    {{ form.media }}
    <p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ wizard.management_form }}
    {% if wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
        {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
            {{ form.as_table }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {{ wizard.form }}
    {% endif %}
    </table>
    {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
    <button name="wizard_goto_step" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% translate "first step" %}</button>
    <button name="wizard_goto_step" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% translate "prev step" %}</button>
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{% translate "next step" %}"/>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'dashboard_assets/js/admin.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'dashboard_assets/js/dashboard-custom.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock js %}

I tried to make the forms as simple as possible and I was expecting the form to submit on the last step and the done method of the WizardView to be called. Lastly when I click the submit button, for some reason 2 request are made at the same time. Please below.


[30/Aug/2024 17:44:46] "POST /user-accounts/addlisting/ HTTP/1.1" 200 15114
[30/Aug/2024 17:44:46] "GET /user-accounts/addlisting/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14275




I'm unable to comment (working on that), so I'll engage here. Are you reaching your httpresponse? is that happening?
IDK if this will solve it, but i recently worked with the forms wizard and got my stuff working.
i do have the following section above my done() section which will validate/clean the form (changing form name to yours)
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
       context = super(AddListing, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
       return context

My done looks something like the following (again, attempting to adapt):
def done(self,form_list,**kwargs):
    # I want to review/validate/save data.. then submit for processing
    newRec=AddListing(**self.get_all_cleaned_data())
    newRec.full_clean()
    newRec.save()
    return redirect('app:url')

if you're response isn't happening already, i'm not sure the above will solve your problem, but i guess any help is better than none.
